# Connection refused when user's home directory is changed

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, sftp

I am setting up a user account to log into the server through SSH. The user name is 'sam'

```
sudo useradd sam
```

This created a /home/sam directory. I created a .ssh directory and wrote a public key to the authorized_keys file within this directory. I was able to log into the system using Putty and FileZilla (using the corresponding private key, of course)

However now I do this:

```
sudo usermod -d  some_other_directory  sam
```

Then I created .ssh within the above new home directory and created the authorized_keys file....all with appropriate permissions and ownerships (sam owner and sam group). I am not able to log into the system at all now....The second I change the home directory back to /home/sam  I am again able to log in.....any ideas about what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: is ownship OK along the path from `/` to `some_other_directory` ?

Comment: 'sam' is the owner of 'some_other_directory'...but this directory is deep into the system and the directories above it are owned by other users.

Comment: you need `r-x` access for sam all along the path from `/`

Comment: And how do I do that :) The new home directory for the user is /var/www/html/websitename/html

Comment: And how do I do that? :) The 'some_other_directory' is /var/www/html/websitename/html

Comment: You will probably have wrong SELinux labels on the home directory, if you moved it into non-standard location. Fix the labels and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` or other similar file depends on your system. There is a chance you will find some records like:

```
sshd[32458]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory some_other_directory
```

And after you chould check ownerships and modes for that folder and fix it accoridngly: your home directory and .ssh must not have group and others write permissions.

Comment: I did chmod 700 for the .ssh directory and chmod 600 for the authorized_keys directory. What permissions do I need to set for the user's home directory? Thanks!

Comment: Home directory should have 700, 751 or 755. Personaly I prefer 751, you could also try that mode.

Comment: Didn't work! I have all the permissions set up correctly. Putty is saying 'server refused our key' even though the authorized key file was copied from /home/sam (which was working just fine)

Comment: Please share permissions, last errors from ssh and number of lines on `authorized_keys` file. Next commands may help you: `whoami; ls -ld some_other_directory some_other_directory/.ssh some_other_directory/.ssh/authorized_keys; wc -l some_other_directory/.ssh/authorized_keys; egrep -c -w 'ssh-[rd]sa' some_other_directory/.ssh/authorized_keys; sudo tail /var/log/secure`. And you could add this information to your main post so it will be easier to read and understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have `Selinux`enabled and it blocks access for `authorized_keys` outside `/home` folder. Here is [Centos forum thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9122) how to fix that issue.